# How to define "field change" event in hook_notifications()

Tags: 7, hooks, notifications

I want to define my own events using [hook_notifications()](https://drupal.org/node/407338). I started with the tutorial [here](https://drupal.org/node/1199556). I've been analyzing the code and so far I've been trying to find out where exactly I am supposed to describe the "field changes value" action.

My presumption is that that under "subscription fields" I should add the two relevant fields.

Later on in the tutorial, in the "event types" part, this code is provided:

```
$types[] = array(
    'type' => 'node',
    'action' => 'update',
    'name' => t('[type-name]: [title]'),
    'line' => t('The [type-name] has been updated'),
    'digest' => array('node', 'nid'),
    'description' => t('Node update'),
  );
  $types[] = array(
    'type' => 'node',
    'action' => 'comment',
    'name' => t('[type-name]: [title]'),
    'line' => t('New comment by [comment-author-name]: [comment-title]'),
    'digest' => array('node', 'nid'),
    'description' => t('Node comment'),
  );
  return $types;
```

These are just examples of a node being updated and a comment being added, but, apart from guessing, I don't know how a "custom field being updated" event should be defined and I would be happy to get some help on that.

Comment: Sorry to have to be the one to break it to you...you've been following a tutorial for Drupal 6

Comment: Oops. I'm looking but I can't find the relevant docs for Drupal 7 notification hooks, could you point me to the correct docs?

Comment: I don't think there are any to be honest - on a quick search around google there are quite a few people looking for the same thing with no resolution. Your best bet would be a feature request to the notifications module itself